# How to calculate average of monthly sales data from python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have below pandas dataframe which has employees sales data for october month.

```
            Employee            Timerange    Dials   Conn  Conv     Mtg Bkd     Talk            Dial 
0           Ricky Ponting       10/3 - 10/7  1,869   102   60.0        2.0      3h:08m          5h:23m
1           Adam Gilchrist      10/3 - 10/7  1,336    53   30.0        1.0      1h:10m          3h:58m
2           Michael Clarke      10/3 - 10/7  1,960    74   42.0        1.0      2h:02m          5h:28m
3           Shane Warne         10/3 - 10/7  1,478    62   45.0        1.0      1h:55m          4h:07m
```

Schema -

```
#   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------     --------------  -----
 1   Timerange  40 non-null     object
 2   Dials      40 non-null     object
 3   Conn       40 non-null     int64
 4   Conv      39 non-null     float64
 5   Mtg Bkd  39 non-null     float64
 6   Talk      40 non-null     object
 7   Dial︎    40 non-null     object
```

I basically want to check the  dials-to-connection and the dials-to-conversation average rates of the whole team for the month. Example output like below  -

```
 Month     Dials    Conn      Dials -> Conn      Dials -> Conv
October    60517    2702         0.045                0.026
```

I tried using pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Timerange']).Month and separate the column but it is giving me error dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 10/3 - 10/7. Please help me guys

Comment: what if Timerange  is `10/30 - 11/5` ?  What month will it be?

Comment: the data is only for october month and hence the last record of data frame has timerange 10/24 - 10/28

Comment: @Tushaar, for example how the dials-to-connection average rate is calculated ?

Comment: @abokey first find sum of conn column/total number of employees , then sum of dials column/ total nubmer of columns and finally divide them, that's it

Comment: What do you mean by _total number of columns_ ?

Comment: sorry it is total number of employees..... it was a typo @abokey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposition using [**`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [**`pandas.DataFrame.apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) :

```
#Extract the month number from the start date and convert it to a month name
df["Month"]= pd.to_datetime(df["Timerange"].str.extract(r"(\d+)/\d+", expand=False), format="%m").dt.month_name()

#Convert comma separated strings to numbers
df["Dials"]= df["Dials"].str.replace(",", "").astype(float)

out = (
        df.groupby("Month", as_index=False)
                .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"Dials": x["Dials"].sum(),
                                            "Conn": x["Conn"].sum(),
                                            "Dials -> Conn": x["Conn"].sum()/x["Dials"].sum(),
                                            "Dials -> Conv": x["Conv"].sum()/x["Dials"].sum()}))

      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

     Month   Dials   Conn  Dials -> Conn  Dials -> Conv
0  October  6643.0  291.0       0.043806       0.026645
```

Comment: Wow.. worked like a charm... but could you please explain also since it's hard for me to understand why you are using series and how does the first line work here?

Comment: i am unable to understand this line df["Month"]= pd.to_datetime(df["Timerange"].str.extract(r"(\d+)/\d+", expand=False), format="%m").dt.month_name()

Comment: also could you please explain how group by and apply is working here along with series

Comment: I've added some comments to explain the first two lines. And regarding `pd.Series`, this one is a pandas constructor to create series (columns). So when used with `.groupby`, it allows you to create multiple aggregations and hence multiple columns. Read more here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that your Timerange always starts with the month you are interested in, and that all data comes from the same year (this year). If these are reasonable assumptions, this works:

```
emps = [
    "Ricky Ponting", "Adam Gilchrist", "Michael Clarke", "Shane Warne"
]

timeranges = [
    "10/3 - 10/7", "10/3 - 10/7", "10/3 - 10/7", "10/3 - 10/7"
]

dials = [1869, 1336, 1960, 1478]
conn = [102, 53, 74, 62]
conv = [60, 30, 42, 45]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Employee": emps,
        "Timerange": timeranges,
        "Dials": dials,
        "Conn": conn,
        "Conv": conv
    }
)

import datetime

def get_month(row):
    month = int(row["Timerange"].split("/")[0])
    return datetime.date(year=2022, month=month, day=1).strftime("%B")

df["Month"] = df.apply(get_month, axis=1)

sums = df.groupby("Month").sum()
sums["Dials -> Conn"] = sums["Conn"] / sums["Dials"]
sums["Dials -> Conv"] = sums["Conv"] / sums["Dials"]
sums
```

[image]

Comment: getting KeyError: 'Dials'

Comment: i don't think you are passing row object anywhere which you are using in get_month function

Comment: My code runs, so I am not sure where you are getting the KeyError from? Also, the get_month gets its row argument from the apply method of the dataframe, if called with axis=1 which passes rows.

Comment: Also, i just want month name under month column name which is october but you are showing the date and year field also

Comment: Yes, I suggest you use the oneliner from @abokey 's answer. Apart from that, our solutions do the exact same thing, but mine is split into more rows for readability. Choose either one you see fit.

Comment: great solution by you as well :)

Comment: Thank. I changed the code in get_month to give you the month name.